# Meaning of "Spoil Yourself Silly on a Shoestring"

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

What does *Spoil Yourself Silly on a Shoestring* mean? It is the title of a chapter of the book I'm reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not translate it part by part:

From Oxford Advanced American Dictionary:

> - spoil someone/yourself: to make someone/yourself happy by doing something special
> - (IDIOM) on a shoestring (informal): using very little money

*silly* in such contexts means *so much*.

The sentence means *make yourself happy by using very little money many times, don't use all of your money at once*.

Comment: That's it! You're right.

Answer (score 8):

To *spoil yourself* is to treat yourself, like a parent who buys too many toys and sweets for a child.

*Silly* here means to do it excessively, the idea being you would do it until it makes you silly.

*On a shoestring* means on a meagre budget.

So the whole thing means "Treat yourself excessively on a budget".

Comment: I do too, but I should translate this title into persian. ;)